# Why doesn't asp.net button work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, webforms

I have used this behind asp button click function. It works on local system but not after begin deployed on server. Why ?

```
public void EmployeeDeActivation()
{     
    hdnfieldSessionPersonalInfoID.Value = "0";
    Session["ExtraPersonalInfoID"] = 0;
    Response.Redirect("EmployeeInformation.aspx", false);      
}
```

.aspx code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEmployeeActivated" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="btnEmployeeActivated_Click"
            CssClass="btn btn-rounded pull-right btnEmployeeActivated" />
```

i.e. when i click button when on local system, it hits then button event and refrehes the page but when it doesn't work like then button click never hits.

Update:

```
 protected void btnEmployeeActivated_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            EmployeeDeActivation();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Where is the view code and the handler which eventually calls this method? That may help troubleshoot the issue. Above code is not going to be of much help.

Comment: @CodingYoshi check updated question

Comment: Where is the code for btnEmployeeActivated_Click handler?

Comment: @CodingYoshi check nwo

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this method need to accept an event handler?  E.g.

protected virtual void OnClick(
    EventArgs e
)

Also, the part of code where you set your hidden is not needed as you redirect after.

Also it has the wrong name as it doesn't match the onclick name

Answer (score 0):

Try to [enable Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx) and log on every method in the page. Try to visualize what your code is doing during postback.

Another useful tool is [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

asp button property "Visible" is set to false in your code. how come button is rendering at first place ?